# How to print Graphene-Django / Graphene-Python Exceptions to the Console for Debugging?

Tags: debugging, exception, graphene-python, graphene-django

When a GraphQL Error occurs, I cannot easily know where it occured. I have to spend unnecessary time trying to track it down. How do I get a Traceback printed in the console of my text editor?

Answer (score 2):

I answered my own question by accessing the GraphQL error(s) with result.errors, iterating through the list, and using python's print_tb function to print the Traceback.

Does anyone have a different or better way of doing it?

## Example usage of the print_graphql_errors function:

```
from django.conf.settings import DEBUG

result = schema.execute(
    mutation_str, context_value=request, variable_values=variable_values
)

if result.errors is None:
    return self.handle_success(result)
if DEBUG:
    print_graphql_errors(result.errors)

return self.handle_failure(result)
```

## The print_graphql_errors function:

```
from traceback import print_tb
from django.conf.settings import DEBUG

def print_graphql_errors(errors, raise_error=False):
    if not DEBUG:
        raise Exception(
            'DevError: This function should not be called in production'
        )

    assert errors, 'DevError: The "errors" parameter cannot be None'
    print_after = []
    current_error = None

    print('######################################################################')
    print('Manually Generated Traceback (with the print_graphql_errors function):')
    print(f'There are {len(errors)} errors:')

    for i, error in enumerate(errors):
        print(f'{i + 1}) ', error)

    print('######################################################################')

    for error in errors:
        current_error = error
        # FYI: This object has these attributes: (example attribute values)
            # tb_frame <frame at 0x000002DDB844D548, file 'site-packages\\graphql\\execution\\executor.py', line 455, code resolve_or_error>
            # tb_lasti 16
            # tb_lineno 447
            # tb_next <traceback object at 0x000002DDBAFBA388>
        # print('error.locations:', error.locations)
        # print('error.positions:', error.positions)
        try:
            print_tb(error.stack)
        except AttributeError as e:
            print(e.__traceback__)
            print(f'Warning: An error occured while trying to print the traceback: {e}. It has the following attributes instead: {dir(error)}')
            print_after.append(error)

    if len(print_after):
        print('###################################################################')
        print(f'Number of errors without the "stack" attribute: {len(print_after)}')
        print('###################################################################')

    if raise_error:
        for error in print_after:
            raise error

        raise current_error
```